# Is it acceptable to use various training sets for the individual models when using a majority vote classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

So I am trying to use a majority vote classifier combining different models  and I was wondering if it is acceptable to use different training sets for the individual models (including different features) if these sets all come from one larger dataset?

Thanks